# Connecting to xmpp on Android device

Tags: android, xmpp

I'm trying to connect to my companies xmpp server on Android. I'm not too familiar with how xmpp should work so I'm a bit confused on configuring it.

I have it setup in Pidgin and can't figure out how to carry the info over. In pidgin my info is something like this -

Name: mark@thezone
Username: mark
Domain: thezone
Server: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
Port: 5222

So when I'm trying to join an app, I don't know what to put for anything. I have tried every combination I can think of.

Is my username mark or mark@thezone? Should the server be the ip or xmpp.(ip) or thezone.ip or what. Is the host the same as the ip? I've tried every combination and none work but if I atleast know the format I should be able to troubleshoot a bit better.

Comment: What is the error you get? Provide the logcat and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @user230250 I simply get "connection error". I'm not totally sure where the logs are for Xabber, however I have tried different combinations. I've set my username to mark and mark@thezone, I've set the server to the ip, I've set the server to thezone.ip, I've tried setting the server to "xmpp.(ip)", I've tried setting the host to the same as the ip, I've tried setting it differently from the ip, and different combinations of all 3 of those settings